# scrollbar and datagrid problem

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, scrollbar

In my datagrid I have in the rowdetailsTemplate a stackpanel that has in it anther datagrid.
when I open a row that has in it a datagrid with about 20 rows and I try scrolling with the scrollbar (of the main grid) using the bottom arrow it wouldn't scroll down.

Comment: Please be more spesific when you ask a question..

Answer (score 0):

For have scroll panel you need `<ScrollViewer>` component as show in this post :[Scrolling In Silverlight Panels](http://www.thereforesystems.com/scrolling-in-silverlight-panels/)

It's possible add this component inside your grid.

Comment: The problem is that when I have many rows in the rowdetailTemple datagrid the scroll gets stuck